# Resolving Maven Dependency in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to resolve a maven dependency in my eclipse project.

The dependency has already been downloaded into my maven dependencies folder (as can be seen below)

[image: Dependency Folder]

[image: Relevant Dependency]

However, the import statement still isn't resolving.

In my java build path, the Maven Dependencies folder is present.

[image: Maven Dependencies]

So far, I've tried rebuilding the project on the command line and refreshing it in eclipse; I've  tried rebuilding it in in eclipse itself; and I've tried updating the project in eclipse.

Nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's my POM file for those of you who asked.

[image: POM 1]
[image: POM 2]
[image: POM 3]

Comment: What's your pom look like?

Comment: Is selenium only available in "test" scope in the pom.xml?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Just uploaded the images

Comment: @axelclk Yes, it is

Comment: @Harry so try to write your example under "src/test/java" path

Comment: @axelclk Okay, trying that now. Yes it worked!

Comment: @axelclk So the <scope><scope> tag specifies the folder the dependency is visible from? What if I wanted the dependency to be visible from anywhere in my project?

Comment: Don't  know if this is possible. Why not adding dependency to "normal" scope" in pom.xml.
So Maven is in sync with project files

Comment: when you share your pom.xml, why using screenshot instead of just copy/paste text  ? 

Answer (score 1):

Your dependency is set as under the `test` scope. This means that it's only available in test classes (e.g. `src/test/java`). If you want to use it in your main app `src/main/java` remove the test scope.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use eclipse but the general idea is to delete all dependencies in your dependency folder and rebuild or you can also change the version of the dependency that is throwing the error. Sometimes, the name of the class you are calling may be changed in the version you are using.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try that now.

Answer (score 0):

With a right-mouse click on the project node in the ***Package Explorer*** and selecting menu ***Maven -> Update Project...***, you can update the Maven dependencies.

You also have to keep in mind, that Maven has often dependencies in a "`test`" scope in the `pom.xml`. In that case you can use these dependencies only under the `src/test/java` path.

Comment: Yup, that was one of the things I tried. No luck, unfortunately.